# Set upload_max_filesize for OpsWorks php app server stack

Tags: php, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I'm running a pretty standard, non-EBS backed PHP app server on OpsWorks. It hosts a site built with Expression Engine and has only a single custom chef recipe that sets write permissions for PHP to the directories required to be writabled by EE.

I use backend image processing anyway, so I would like the client to be able to upload JPGs straight out of camera and also short video files. This is where the default php.ini upload_max_filesize and post_max_size of 2MB is a limitation.

I have overridden these in .htaccess, but I get the impression that this is not a first class solution. I would prefer being able to specify these in the custom chef JSON or, if needs be, in the custom chef recipe.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm also trying change some PHP settings, ideally by modifying php.ini with chef scripts, but everything I do seems to break stuff. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

OpsWorks doesn't overwrite anything of your php.ini by default.
There is no template or attribute that you could overwrite.

But as you said with a custom cookbook this is possible.
Just put it in you setup lifecycle event and let it write your php.ini from a template or replace in the default one with scripts like `sed` the post_max_size.

Answer (score 0):

I just thought to drop this here, as I faced a similar issue today.

You can set the php.ini values in your .htaccess file

The code snippet below set the upload_max_filesize and post_max_size.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 500M
php_value post_max_size 510M
```